# Calling method / refreshing data in another form

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have 2 forms - **frmMain** and **frmChild**

The **frmChild** form is declared as I run **frmMain**

```
frmChild form1 = new frmChild();
```

I also have a button that runs a method to open the frmChild form.

```
OpenForm(form1);
```

The question is, how can I update data / call desired method on the **frmChild** form while I'm still on the **frmMain** form? I need to do it on the existing instance of the form, without creating a new one.

I've tried doing it this way, but can't access the method

The **frmMain** class

```
public partial class frmMain: DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
{
     frmChild form1 = new frmChild();


     private void UpdateDataOnChildForm()
     {
         form1.UpdateData(); // cant access this method...
     }

}
```

The **frmChild** class

```
public partial class frmChild : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
{
     public void UpdateData()
    {
         //update data here...
    }

}
```

any tips will be appreciated

Comment: `form1.DoSomething()`?

Comment: Just call a function on the form instance like @Guy suggests. Or if this is not the answer, try to explain your specific question.

Comment: you could use something like [`publish / subscribe`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish–subscribe_pattern) system, where you just notify all your subscribers when a change was published relevant for them (then it doesn't really matter how many subscribers you might have). Just don't forget to unsubscribe when that form closes

Comment: I can't access the method doing it this way @Guy

Comment: @bapster Is it `private`? make it `public` than.

Comment: It is public and I still can't access it @Guy

Comment: @bapster Add to the question the method you are trying to call in `frmChild` and how you are trying to access it.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is to have a singleton object, you might wanna look at https://csharpindepth.com/articles/singleton for this

Comment: @bapster What is `DoStuff()`? `UpdateData()`? and by *cant access this method* you mean you can't see it in autocomplete or something else?

Comment: Yes, exactly I can't see it in autocomplete.

The DoStuff() method updates the data within the form. Downloads data from db and updates control's text properties. 

The UpdateData() just calls the DoStuff() method on the frmChild form. @Guy

Comment: @Guy I updated the question once again, noticed a little mistake. I need to call the UpdateData() method on the child form

Comment: Ok, I found the problem. I was calling the wrong form since had 2 similar forms.

thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
   private frmChild form1 = new frmChild();
   
   private DoSomeActionOnfrmChild()
   {
      form1.SomeAction();
   }
}
public partial class frmChild : Form
{
   public void SomeAction()
   {}
}
```

Comment: In your edit you need to call UpdateData()
   private void UpdateDataOnChildForm()
     {
         form1.UpdateData();
     }

Answer (score 0):

```
`public partial class MainForm : Form
{
   private void btnMain_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoginForm lfrm = new LoginForm;
        LoginForm.ShowDialog();
    }
   private void SecureMethod(){//do sth};
}
public partial class LoginForm : Form
{
   private void btnok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SecureMethod(); //is not true
        this.close(); //close loginform
    }
}`
```